# Complex query extremely slow when grouping or ordering - index suggestions?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

So, I've been given the task of replicating functionality we currently handle via code, within MySQL.

The query below works beautifully, bringing back 245,000 rows in 40ms, however as soon as you touch it with a group or order, it takes over 6s.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what changes need making to the indexes or potentially how to modify the query to improve it?

Thanks

---

### Without any grouping or ordering

```
select 
    s.id as sensorid,
    s.sensortypeid,
    COALESCE(s.pulserate, 1) as pulserate,
    COALESCE(s.correctionFactor, 1) as correctionFactor,

    ur.id as unitrateid,
    COALESCE(ur.priceperkwh, 0) as priceperkwh,
    COALESCE(ur.duosCharges, 0) as duosCharges,

    IF(t.blnnonunitratecharges, t.nonunitratecharge/48, 0) as nonunitratecost,
    IF(t.blnFeedIn, COALESCE(t.feedInRate, 0), 0) as feedInRate,
    IF(t.blnRoc, COALESCE(t.rocRate, 0), 0) as rocRate,

    from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(srs.dateTimeStamp)/(30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey

from sensorreadings srs
    inner join sensorpoints sp on (sp.id = srs.sensorpointid)
    inner join sensors s on (s.id = sp.sensorid)
    left join unitrates ur on ur.id = (
        select 
            ur.id 
        from unitrates ur, tariffs t, companyhubs ch
        where 
            ur.tariffid = t.id and
            t.companyid = ch.companyid and 
            ch.hubid = s.hubid and 
            t.utilitytypeid = s.utilitytypeid and 
            (srs.dateTimeStamp between t.startdate and t.enddate) and 
            ((time(srs.dateTimeStamp) between ur.starttime and ur.endtime) and 
            (ur.dayMask & POW(2, WEEKDAY(srs.dateTimeStamp)) <> 0) and 
            (ur.monthMask & POW(2, MONTH(srs.dateTimeStamp) - 1) <> 0)) 
        order by 
            t.startdate desc, 
            ur.starttime desc 
        limit 0, 1
    )
    left join tariffs t on (t.id = ur.tariffid)
where 
    s.id = 5289
```

### With grouping and ordering

```
select 
    s.id as sensorid,
    s.sensortypeid,
    COALESCE(s.pulserate, 1) as pulserate,
    COALESCE(s.correctionFactor, 1) as correctionFactor,

    ur.id as unitrateid,
    COALESCE(ur.priceperkwh, 0) as priceperkwh,
    COALESCE(ur.duosCharges, 0) as duosCharges,

    IF(t.blnnonunitratecharges, t.nonunitratecharge/48, 0) as nonunitratecost,
    IF(t.blnFeedIn, COALESCE(t.feedInRate, 0), 0) as feedInRate,
    IF(t.blnRoc, COALESCE(t.rocRate, 0), 0) as rocRate,

    min(srs.reading) as minReading,
    avg(srs.reading) as avgReading,

    from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(srs.dateTimeStamp)/(30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey

from sensorreadings srs
    inner join sensorpoints sp on (sp.id = srs.sensorpointid)
    inner join sensors s on (s.id = sp.sensorid)
    left join unitrates ur on ur.id = (
        select 
            ur.id 
        from unitrates ur, tariffs t, companyhubs ch
        where 
            ur.tariffid = t.id and
            t.companyid = ch.companyid and 
            ch.hubid = s.hubid and 
            t.utilitytypeid = s.utilitytypeid and 
            (srs.dateTimeStamp between t.startdate and t.enddate) and 
            ((time(srs.dateTimeStamp) between ur.starttime and ur.endtime) and 
            (ur.dayMask & POW(2, WEEKDAY(srs.dateTimeStamp)) <> 0) and 
            (ur.monthMask & POW(2, MONTH(srs.dateTimeStamp) - 1) <> 0)) 
        order by 
            t.startdate desc, 
            ur.starttime desc 
        limit 0, 1
    )
    left join tariffs t on (t.id = ur.tariffid)
where 
    s.id = 5289
group by timeKey
order by timeKey desc
```

**Schemas**

```
CREATE TABLE `sensorreadings` (
    `sensorpointid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reading` decimal(15,5) NOT NULL,
    `dateTimeStamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`sensorpointid`,`dateTimeStamp`),
    KEY `sensormetricid` (`sensormetricid`),
    KEY `sensorreadings_timestamp` (`dateTimeStamp`,`sensorpointid`),
    KEY `sensorpointid` (`sensorpointid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sensorpoints` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sensorid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `hubpointid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `pointlabel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `pointhash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `target` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
    `tolerance` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT '0',
    `blnlivepoint` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_sensorpoints_sensors` (`sensorid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_sensorpoints_sensors` FOREIGN KEY (`sensorid`) REFERENCES `sensors` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8824 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `sensors` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hubid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sensortypeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
    `pulserate` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `utilitytypeid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `correctionfactor` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_sensors_sensortypes` (`sensortypeid`),
    KEY `FK_sensors_hubs` (`hubid`),
    KEY `FK_sensors_utilitytypes` (`utilitytypeid`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_sensors_hubs` FOREIGN KEY (`hubid`) REFERENCES `hubs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_sensors_sensortypes` FOREIGN KEY (`sensortypeid`) REFERENCES `sensortypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5503 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `tariffs` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `companyid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `utilitytypeid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `startdate` date NOT NULL,
    `enddate` date NOT NULL,
    `blnnonunitratecharges` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `nonunitratecharge` decimal(16,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    `blnFeedIn` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `blnRoc` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `rocRate` decimal(16,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    `feedInRate` decimal(16,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `companyid` (`companyid`,`utilitytypeid`,`startdate`,`enddate`),
    KEY `startdate` (`startdate`,`enddate`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `unitrates` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `tariffid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `priceperkwh` decimal(16,8) NOT NULL,
    `starttime` time NOT NULL,
    `endtime` time NOT NULL,
    `duoscharges` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
    `dayMask` int(11) DEFAULT '127',
    `monthMask` int(11) DEFAULT '4095',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FK_unitrates_tariffs` (`tariffid`),
    KEY `times` (`starttime`,`endtime`),
    KEY `masks` (`dayMask`,`monthMask`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_unitrates_tariffs` FOREIGN KEY (`tariffid`) REFERENCES `tariffs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3104 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Explains**

*Without groups/ordering*

```
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                   | key                     | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                        | 
|----|--------------------|-------|--------|---------------------------------|-------------------------|---------|-------------------------------|------|----------------------------------------------| 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | s     | const  | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY                 | 4       | const                         | 1    | NULL                                         | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | sp    | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_sensorpoints_sensors | FK_sensorpoints_sensors | 5       | const                         | 1    | Using index                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | srs   | ref    | PRIMARY,sensorpointid           | PRIMARY                 | 4       | dbnameprod.sp.id              | 211  | Using index                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | ur    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY                 | 4       | func                          | 1    | Using where                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                         | PRIMARY                 | 4       | dbnameprod.ur.tariffid        | 1    | NULL                                         | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ch    | ref    | hubid                           | hubid                   | 5       | const                         | 1    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t     | ref    | PRIMARY,companyid,startdate     | companyid               | 10      | dbnameprod.ch.companyid,const | 1    | Using where; Using index                     | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ur    | ref    | FK_unitrates_tariffs,times      | FK_unitrates_tariffs    | 4       | dbnameprod.t.id               | 1    | Using where                                  |
```

*With ordering/grouping*

```
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys                                                 | key                     | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                        | 
|----|--------------------|-------|--------|---------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------|---------|-------------------------------|------|----------------------------------------------| 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | s     | const  | PRIMARY                                                       | PRIMARY                 | 4       | const                         | 1    | Using temporary; Using filesort              | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | sp    | ref    | PRIMARY,FK_sensorpoints_sensors                               | FK_sensorpoints_sensors | 5       | const                         | 1    | Using index                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | srs   | ref    | PRIMARY,sensormetricid,sensorreadings_timestamp,sensorpointid | PRIMARY                 | 4       | dbnameprod.sp.id              | 211  | Using index                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | ur    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                       | PRIMARY                 | 4       | func                          | 1    | Using where                                  | 
| 1  | PRIMARY            | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                       | PRIMARY                 | 4       | dbnameprod.ur.tariffid        | 1    | NULL                                         | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ch    | ref    | hubid                                                         | hubid                   | 5       | const                         | 1    | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t     | ref    | PRIMARY,companyid,startdate                                   | companyid               | 10      | dbnameprod.ch.companyid,const | 1    | Using where; Using index                     | 
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | ur    | ref    | FK_unitrates_tariffs,times                                    | FK_unitrates_tariffs    | 4       | dbnameprod.t.id               | 1    | Using where                                  |
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Thanks for getting back to me. I've added `EXPLAIN` analysis - is there anything that I need to add to the OP?

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are grouping and ordering for a calculated field `timeKey` and db doesnt have any index on that field.

So db need to calculate all rows before doing the group by and then do the ordering and without index cant speed up the calculations.

Suggestion: Create a time field on your db and add index for that field.

Comment: Thanks Juan. The calculated field `timeKey` is dynamic (i.e. `(30*60)` can change depending on user requirements) - whilst doing some testing, removing the left join onto `unitrates` speeds things up considerably whilst grouping/ordering? Any thoughts?

Comment: Is a similar problem. In that join you are trying to find a match with a subquery. And that one doesnt have a precalculated index. But dont make sense the first query run faster with the same join. I suggest you try to optimize the subquery alone first because is also using calculated field to make the joins

Answer (score 0):

Before looking into the performance, let's discuss the likelihood that the query is broken.

When doing a `GROUP BY`, all the non-aggregate `SELECT` values should be included in the `GROUP BY`.  Otherwise, any random value can be delivered.

Furthermore, this pattern:

```
SELECT ..., AVG(a.x)
    FROM a 
    JOIN b ON ...
    GROUP BY a.id
```

*usually* leads to an inflation of the number of rows (due to the `JOIN`), followed by computing the aggregates over the inflated number of rows.  Add `COUNT(*)` to see if I am right for your case.  For `COUNT`, the answer can be blatantly wrong; for `AVG` it can be subtly wrong; for `MIN` it is probably correct.  And finally the `GROUP BY` deflates the number of rows.

The *usual* cure is to compute the aggregates *without* the `JOINs` (I am not sure if it is possible in your case).  Maybe something like...

```
...
JOIN (
    SELECT  min(srs.reading) as minReading,
            avg(srs.reading) as avgReading,
            from_unixtime(FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(srs.dateTimeStamp)/
                (30*60))*(30*60)) as timeKey
        FROM srs
        GROUP BY timeKey
      ) AS r
JOIN ...
```

It is usually a 'bad' idea to have `date` and `time` in separate columns.  A `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` is easier to compare against, etc.  (I am unclear on what you are doing with your separate date and time.)  This can also be a performance issue.

The 3 tables lead to a bunch of `JOINing`, making the `WHERE s.id = 5289` hard to transfer to srs.  You may need to rethink the schema as another performance issue.

I realize the values are different, but could

```
    order by 
        t.startdate desc, 
        ur.starttime desc
```

be replaced by

```
    order by srs.dateTimeStamp
```

That might lead to to being able to us an index.

I'm surprised you are using `DECIMAL(m,n)` instead of `FLOAT` for sensor readings.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I had completely forgotten I had posted this. Ended up finding a solution but ultimately it's not suitable for what I had hoped for. After making some changes, I was able to return 100k rows in approx 400ms, however if I wanted to limit that to only 10 rows, it'd still take 400ms. Re separate Time/Date, we have tariffs which are based on dates and then each tariff has variable costs depending on the day, month and time. Thanks again :)